# finding total with Binary Search Tree in C

Tags: c, recursion, binary-search-tree

let's say I have BST with

```
          50
         /  \
        30   70
       / \   / \
      20 40 60 80
```

My total depth should be 1 + 2 + 2 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3= 17, and I have total depth function

```
int Total_Depth(struct node* node, int depth){
if (node==NULL){
    return 0;}
else{
    return depth + Total_Depth(node->left, depth++) + Total_Depth(node->right, depth++);
}
```

When I call Total_Depth function in main() `printf("%d\n", Total_Depth(root, 0))` I get 12 rather than 17. Can anyone explain me why this is the case? I can't really figure out a way to find total depth

Comment: Perhaps `if (node==NULL){
    return depth;}
else{
    return depth + Total_Depth(node->left, depth) + Total_Depth(node->right, depth);
}`?

Comment: @chux `return 0` is correct for a nonexistent node.

Comment: @chux - you are not  incrementing the value of depth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call your recursion function with post-increment **depth++**.
The post-increment operator increments the variable after you use it, so it will only increment the variable after the recursive function is returned.
For this, in recursion function calling you should not use post-increment.

So, you should replace your **depth++** with **depth+1**.

```
  return depth + Total_Depth(node->left, depth+1) + 
  Total_Depth(node->right, depth+1);
```

Comment: @Ben Han- accept the answer if its help you so that community know the answer help you

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain why the OPs answer using post-increment is wrong.